# How does one prove that a computational theorem prover is correct?

Tags: proof-verification, theorem-provers

There are many computational theorem provers, such as Z3 (http://z3.codeplex.com/). Such provers employ many thousands of lines of code. How can one prove that the results are correct and can be trusted?

Comment: Even if there was such a proof, Donald Knuth would say: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it." :)

Comment: @PhoemueX, indeed. My interest is in autonomous systems, where it is certainly desirable to have provably correct decisions being made by a machine. An analogous approach used for high-reliability engineering employs triple-modular-redundancy (TMR). Three different implementations, then majority voting on the results. I presume one could employ the same approach for this application using three different logic solvers and ensure that their results are equivalent (perhaps yet another challenge).